# Does pqxx::pipeline support prepared statement

Tags: c++, sql, postgresql, libpqxx

Can we execute Prepared statement(parametrised query) inside `pqxx::pipeline`,
we can insert plain sql statement like:

`SELECT * FROM table`

but can we do something like given below

```
pqxx::connection c;
c.prepare("SELECT_QUERY", "SELECT * FROM table");
pqxx::work w(c);
pqxx::pipeline p(w);
w.insert("SELECT_QUERY");
w.complete()
```

Thanks